# How to get rid of blanks in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace, lemmatization

I have successfully managed to get rid of `'\n'` in a list, but I can't seem to get rid of a blank.

This is what I've done:

```
from pymystem3 import Mystem
m = Mystem()
user_flash = Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('question', flat=True)
user_flash_ = [item.replace('\n', ' ') for item in m.lemmatize(" ".join(user_flash))]
```

But when I try to do the same for "", it doesn't work.

So, before I did anything, the list looked something like: `['word1', '', 'word2', '\n']`
After implementing my code above I'm left with:  `['word1', '', 'word2']`
How can I get rid of that one blank? The following...

```
user_flash_clean = [item.replace('', ' ') for item in user_flash_]
```

...didn't work...

I have found a way to circumvent the problem, but it would be nice if it's possible to just get rid of that blank. (Note - I do have a good reason for doing the `.join` before lemmatizing, but if that is where my problem is coming from, would be happy to explain why I did it, so that I can maybe implement a different solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the words in `user_flash_` based on the length of their [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip)ped value:

```
user_flash_ = ['word1', '', 'word2', '\n']

user_flash_clean = [w for w in user_flash_ if len(w.strip())]
print(user_flash_clean)
```

Output:

```
['word1', 'word2']
```

Note that in a boolean context, strings are false if they are empty (`''`), so you don't actually need `len` in the above code:

```
user_flash_clean = [w for w in user_flash_ if w.strip()]
```

Comment: You don't need to use `len`, strings already take that into account in a boolean context

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to make it clear what was going on, but I will make a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_flash_clean = [item for item in user_flash_ if item.strip()]
```